# jquery load problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem where a jquery load function wipes out the dom element that it is targeted at.

`popup_content.load('form.html #print_options1', function() {popup_content.fadeIn();});`

when popup_content is a div targeted by jquery. A jquery load was previously used to load content into this div without problems. This time, though, the entire div just vanishes.

However, if I add a single javascript alert statement after that call, like so:

```
popup_content.load('form.html #print_options1', function() {popup_content.fadeIn();}); 
alert('after call');
```

then it works(after displaying the annnoying alert, of course). it just seems like some timing issue. has anyone encountered this kind of problem and if so, are there any solutions? any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What does this mean - `popup_content.load('form.html #print_options1'..`? The first parameter to `load()` is always a URL. Once the server returns, the contents of `popup_content` will get wiped and replaced with what the server returns. I'm not sure if I understand your question here.

Comment: well, the url is 'form.html', and #print_options targets the elements which have the id of 'print_options1' to be returned. its on the jquery .load() documentation under "Loading Page Fragments", if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `popup_content` reference gets re-assigned?  The `alert()` call has another effect you may not be considering, the time it takes to get rid of allows that ajax call to finish and the content to be loaded, making that `function() {popup_content.fadeIn();}` happen before `popup_content` changes.  Without the alert, it'll happen *sometime* later...has something happened to your variable by then?

Try instead to not rely on that reference if that's the case, use `this` instead:

```
popup_content.load('form.html #print_options1', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```